# Find the supremum (if exists) of the set $\frac2{\sqrt n}+4$, $n\in\Bbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I already found the $\inf$ of the set but I dont know what about the $\sup$. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does $4\mid n$ mean as a value? An indicator function?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel $|$ probably means "such that"

Comment: Yes, such that.
Edit. Im new in this so please, forgive my abiguous notation.

Comment: @DanielML:  Did you mean what is in the title or $\frac 2{\sqrt n +4}$ or $\frac 2{\sqrt {n+4}}$?   Without parentheses, the title is the correct reading, but I wonder.

Comment: @RossMillikan The first one.

Answer (score 2):

6 is the ans as the sequence is clearly decreasing

Since

$2/\sqrt{n}+4>2/\sqrt{n+1}+4$ as

$\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}$

So
$f(n)>f(n+1)$

Hence $f(1)>f(2)>f(3) \dots $

So $f(1)$ is the maximum, hence the answer!

Comment: Can you tell me please how do you get to that ans?

Comment: Mmm so i was wrong, becouse intuitively I thought that the supremum was going to be 2/5